# How constructor overloading works

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

How to make `Factory.create` to invoke `Task.<init>(SubType)` constructor if I can't modify `Factory.create` method (can modify only `Task` and `SubType` classes)?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factory.create(new SubType());
        // OUTPUT:
        // task instanceof SubType: true
        // callable  (PROBLEM: I want SubType constructor to be invoked)
    }

    public static class SubType implements Callable {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class Task {
        private Callable callable;
        private SubType subType;

        public Task(SubType subType) {
            System.out.println("Subtype");
            this.subType = subType;
        }
        public Task(Callable callable) {
            System.out.println("callable");
            this.callable = callable;
        }
    }

    public static class Factory {

        // If change method argument type to SubType it will invoke 
        // Task.<init>(SubType) constructor, but I can't modify it
        public static Task create(Callable task) {
            System.out.println("task instanceof SubType: " + (task instanceof SubType));
            return new Task(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a public factory static method on `Task` class, and make constructors private, or package private

```
public static class Task {
    private Callable callable;
    private SubType subType;

    private Task(SubType subType) {
        System.out.println("Subtype");
        this.subType = subType;
    }
    private Task(Callable callable) {
        System.out.println("callable");
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    public static Task create ( final Callable callable )
    {
       if ( callable instance of SubTask )
       {
         return new Task( (SubType) callable );
       }

       return new Task( callable );

    }
}

public static class Factory {

    // Note that we are now calling Task's factory method
    public static Task create(Callable task) {
        System.out.println("task instanceof SubType: " + (task instanceof SubType));
        return Task.create(task);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The choice of which overloaded method or constructor is invoked is done at compilation time, based on the *declared* type of the argument. So, even if the actual *concrete* type of `task` is `SubType`, its *declared* type is `Callable`, and the second constructor, taking a Callable as argument, will always be invoked.

So, if you want something different to happen when a Task is constructed with a SubType, then you should test the type of the Callable in the Task constructor:

```
 public static class Task {
    private Callable callable;
    private SubType subType;

    public Task(Callable callable) {
        if (callable instanceof SubTask) {
            System.out.println("Subtype");
            this.subType = subType;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("callable");
            this.callable = callable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this sort of type checking is [often considered bad practice](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).  It should be a good thing that Task can be constructed with subtypes of Callable.  Why should you want to change that?

Comment: @markspace because that's what the OP wants, and he can't change the implementation of Factory, and thus overload the `Factory.create()` method.

Comment: Yes, I realize.  (Actually I'm having a hard time parsing what the OP is trying to say.)  I'm was just letting the OP know what he wants to do is probably bad practice.  I'd like to understand what is goal is, what he's asking to do seems questionable.

Comment: No problem. It might indeed be an XY problem.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the answer! I just trying to modify one open source library. So changes on `Factory.create` will cause too many changes. Your solution is not so bad practice (the library already used it), but `Task` class also has many other fields, which makes it even worse. So, I' m incline to do in @`AlexanderPogrebnyak  way

Comment: Alexander's way is in fact the same way as mine. He's just using an additional factory method doing the instanceof test and calling the appropriate constructor, instead of doing the instanceof test in the constructor itself. That doesn't change much.